# How do I make content derived from css clickable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tooltip, clickable

What should I do such that when i mouse over the '+' , the add to my playlist appear and i'm ABLE to click on the "add to my playlist" and make it linkable. Right now, everytime i try to hover onto add to my playlist, it disappears. :(

(http://i62.tinypic.com/16bhbit.jpg)

Current jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gmraK/

The add to my playlist is generated by

```
.addtoplaylist-video:hover:after{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background:rgba(30,120,160,0.8);
    border-color: rgba(30,120,160,0.8);
    border-right-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    top: -32px;
    color: #ffffff;
    content: 'Add To My Playlist!';
     left: -100px;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 98;
    width: 120px;
    height:15px;
    text-align:center;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#1e78a0', endColorstr='#1e78a0');
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    cursor:pointer;


}
```

html

```
    <div id="video1" class="toggle">
    <span class="addtoplaylist-video">
         <img src="images/addicon.png" width="12" height="11" alt="add" class="addplaylisticonimg"></span>
    <span class="viewplaylist-video">
       <img src="images/viewicon.png" width="17" height="9" alt="viewicon" class="viewplaylisticonimg"> </span>
</div>
```

js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.addtoplaylist-video').on('click', function(){
    $(this).css({'display':'none'});
    $(this).parent('.toggle,.toggle2')
        .find('.viewplaylist-video')
        .css({'display':'block'});
});


$('.viewplaylist-video').on('click', function(){
    $(this).css({'display':'none'});
    $(this).parent('.toggle, .toggle2')
        .find('.addtoplaylist-video')
        .css({'display':'block'});
});



</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/gmraK/2/

I removed the dynamic css div/link and add a div that is only displayed when the parent has the class of active. A class which is added on hover of the toggle element.

So to begin, I removed your `:hover:after`

```
.addtoplaylist-video:hover:after {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background:rgba(30, 120, 160, 0.8);
    border-color: rgba(30, 120, 160, 0.8);
    border-right-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    top: -32px;
    color: #ffffff;
    content:'Add To My Playlist!';
    left: -100px;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 98;
    width: 120px;
    height:15px;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, startColorstr='#1e78a0', endColorstr='#1e78a0');
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Well, to clarify, I modified it to be a standalone element.

**CSS**

```
.addtoplaylist-video-link {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background:rgba(30, 120, 160, 0.8);
    border-color: rgba(30, 120, 160, 0.8);
    border-right-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    bottom: 15px;
    color: #ffffff;
    right: 10px;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 98;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, startColorstr='#1e78a0', endColorstr='#1e78a0');
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Then added the element to the HTML.

**HTML**

```
<a href="" class="addtoplaylist-video-link">Add To My Playlist!</a>
```

Finally, I modified the JavaScript. Originally, you were displaying the content on hover as part of the `:after` pseudo definition. No true interaction within the JavaScript. When you hover over the `.toggle` class, the `.active` class is added to the parent element - `.frame`. The CSS also includes a style to display the new element when the parent has the `.active` class. When mousing out of the parent element the `.active` class is removed and the new div is removed.

**JS**

```
$('.toggle').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).parents('.frame').addClass('active');
});
$('.frame').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('active');    
});
```

Additional CSS from the fiddle includes adjusted positioning of the `.toggle` class elements, etc. Here is the portion to show the hidden element on hover:

```
.active .addtoplaylist-video-link,
.addtoplaylist-video-link:hover{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: @user3534158 hopefully the updated description will help a little more. Ensure that you reference all of the CSS in the fiddle as well. I modified some of the positioning to correct the position of the item to be hovered, etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of displaying your text using css, write that in jQuery. Just give hover method for that '+' and inside that hover method try to display the text and give the link for that it will work. Because jQuery will give you facility to add HTML elements dynamically.